# Enable Gps AlertDialog duplicated

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onresume

I have two methods one to ask the user to connect to internet and the other to connect to gps. I call both methods in the onresume. The problem is that the alertdialog that asks to enable gps shows twice, because the onresume its called again, any way to solve the duplicated call? thanks!

```java
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        enableWifi();
        enableGPS();
}

   public void enableGPS() {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final AlertDialog.Builder gpsBuilder;

        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            gpsBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("GPS uitgeschakled")
                    .setCancelable(false)

                    .setMessage("Uw GPS is uitgeschakled. Schakled het alstublieft in om door te gaan")
                    .setPositiveButton("AANZETTEN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("ANNULEREN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                gpsBuilder.show();
        }

    }
    public void enableWifi(){

        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Uw netwerk is uitgeschakeld.Schakel het alstublieft in om door te gaan")
                    .setTitle("Netwerk is uitgeschakeld")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("AANZETTEN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("ANNULEREN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            builder.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an alertdialog like above, consider using a DialogFragment instead.

Your AlertDialog class will look like:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


    /** Create a new instance of the Dialog Fragment which will display an alert dialog. The alert
     * dialog is always cancelable.
     * @param title The title of the alert dialog.
     * @param message The message.
     * @return An alert dialog.
     */
    public static AlertDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialogFragment frag = new AlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putString("msg", message);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        String message = getArguments().getString("msg");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert_dialog, container, false);
        setCancelable(false);

        if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }

        TextView titleArea = v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleArea.setText(title);

        TextView messageArea = v.findViewById(R.id.message);
        messageArea.setText(message);

        Button okButton = v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        okButton.setText(R.string.ok);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

To show the dialog, you can do the following:

```
AlertDialogFragment dialog = (AlertDialogFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = UpdatingProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(message);
            dialog.show(fragmentManager, tag);
        }
```

where 'tag' would be an identifying String for that dialog, eg. "ALERT".

Note: "fragment_alert_dialog" is just a layout file defining what your alert dialog should look like.

Second Note: An additional advantage of using a fragment is that die dialog will not close when you rotate the device.

Responding to button clicks: 
Sorry, I left this part out. To respond to a button click, you can define an interface for your dialog fragment. Eg

```
/** Should be implemented by all users of this dialog. */
public interface DialogUser {
    /**
     * Will be called when the YES option was selected.
     * @param tag The Dialog Tag, for when there is more than one dialog in the activity.
     **/
    void onDialogYesSelected(String tag);

    /**
     * Will be called when the NO option was selected.
     * @param tag The Dialog Tag, for when there is more than one dialog in the activity.
     **/
    void onDialogNoSelected(String tag);
}
```

Then, when the user presses one of the buttons, you can do:

```
yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getActivity() instanceof DialogUser) {
                    ((YesNoDialogUser) getActivity()).onDialogYesSelected(mTag);
                } else {
                    Log.w("DIALOG", "activity does not implement interface");
                }
                dismiss();
            }
        });
```

The activity calling the dialog should then extend DialogUser and define what should happen on that trigger. You can also pass a special string to your dialog that is used in onDialogYesSelected() so that you know which dialog triggered that particular onDialogYesSelected() call - for example, if your activity had a dialog for the Wifi and another for the GPS, then each of those will give a different tag to onDialogYesSelected()